# JavaScript chart does not appear inside AJAX UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a JavaScript chart (Chart.js) in my C# web forms application. The chart will appear perfectly outside of AJAX UpdatePanel but when I put it inside of UpdatePanel, it would not appear at all. I have read some related threads and I know how to make JavaScript works inside an UpdatePanel but the Chart.js just wouldn't work. What could be the reason & how can I correct this problem?

Any help will be greatly appeciated. Below is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="btnShowData" runat="server" Text="Show Data" OnClick="btnShowData_Click" />
          <br/>
          <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>                    
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

```
protected void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Run method to get data from SQL database, which is converted to string and passed to JavaScript to create the chart.

    string X = stringArrayromDatabase;
    string scriptText = "<script type=text/javascript> chartFunction(" + stringArrayFromDatabase + ") </script>";

    //This code will work, meaning I've done things correctly with the RegisterStartupScriptmethod:
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "alert('Hello')", true);

    //Upon running this code, I expect my JavaScript chart will appear in the web page but it doesn't:
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", scriptText, true);
}
```

EDIT: Below is my JavaScript code for chartFunction(). It's a simple chart that I copied from here: https://jsfiddle.net/red_stapler/u5aanta8/1/. This chart works when I put it outside of AJAX UpdatePanel.

The reason I'm using UpdatePanel is because upon clicking the btnShowData button, I run a method to get data from SQL which is then converted to string & passed to JavaScript code that generates the chart display. Because of this, my whole page is refreshed when I click btnShowData which made me think that I need to use UpdatePanel.

```
function chartFunction(stringArrayFromDatabase) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                data: stringArrayFromDatabase,
            }
        ]
    };
    var option = {
        showLines: true
    };
    var myLineChart = new Chart(canvas,{
        type:'line',
        data:data,
      options:option
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is also important that you share the code of the chartFunction() method, on the other hand, analyzing your code, I think you try to press a button and show the information of the graph, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260986/12520015 It says that you do not need to use the panel update when calling functions.

You can control the update of the chart with javascript, according to the chart js documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have included chartFunction() method in my post.

Comment: I have also edited my post to clarify the reason why I used the update panel. It is because I actually take data from SQL and pass it to JavaScript, I see the whole page is refreshed when I click btnShowData button